# Задача о рюкзаке. Полный перебор

Tags: java, алгоритм

решаю задачу о Рюкзаке, но никак не могу сделать полный перебор. Вот код:

```
public class Backpack {
    static int maxWeight = 80;

    Goods[] goods;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Goods[] goods = {
                new Goods(15, 30),
                new Goods(30, 90),
                new Goods(50, 100)
        };

        System.out.println("Total: " + findBestRes(goods));
    }

    private static int findBestRes(Goods[] goods){
        int max = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
            int temp = goods[i].getValue();
            maxWeight -= goods[i].getWeight();

            for (int j = 0; j < goods.length; j++) {
                if (i != j && maxWeight >= goods[j].getWeight()){
                    temp += goods[j].getValue();
                    maxWeight -= goods[j].getWeight();

                }
            }

            if (temp > max) {
                max = temp;
            }

            maxWeight = 80;
        }

        return max;
    }
}

public class Goods {
    private int weight;
    private int value;

    public Goods(int weight, int value){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }


}
```

не подскажите как правильно реализовать можно или здесь переделывать надо все ?

Comment: а что не работает?

Comment: Локализуйте пожалуйста вашу проблему; Напишите условие задачи, выделите отдельный фрагмент кода и т.д

Comment: полный перебор требует проверки 2^n подмножеств. значит, должен быть код, выполняющий столько итераций (возможно - рекурсивный)

Comment: офф - рюкзак - knapsack ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, давай по порядку.

1. Твой метод не делает полный перебор, а вместо этого пытается взять один из представленных вещей, а всё остальное место забивать случайными вещами, которые могут влезть в рюкзак.
2. Если ты и собрался делать полный перебор, то самый простой вариант - использовать рекурсию. Подобный алгоритм конечно можно написать циклами, но для понимания это будет достаточно сложно.
   Если коротко, я бы рекомендовал иметь класс рюкзака, в котором будет список уже добавленных вещей, оставшаяся грузоподъемность и метод для вычисления стоимости. Тогда в аргументах рекурсивного метода для вычисления результата будет текущий портфель и следующая по порядку вещь (пожалуйста, не надо комбинировать 1-2-3, 1-3-2, 2-1-3 итд. Всегда можно идти по принципу увелечения индекса. Перебор останется полным, но это на много сократит количество итераций). Если вещь (скажем, с индексом 3) поместилась - пробуем добавить вещи от 4 до n. Если нет - высчитываем стоимость. Дальше всё понятно. (Уж простите, реализованные задачи с инета копировать не хочу. При желании можно найти)
3. Полный перебор - далеко не оптимальный алгоритм. Есть алгоритмы намного быстрее и проще. Если от тебя не требуют реализации конкретного метода - пересмотри другие варианты решения